# how to get data from forEach click from loop into another named function

Tags: javascript, foreach, named

I am trying to get the dataset of a clicked link from within a forEach loop. I am a bit stumped as to how to get that value into another function.

```
   this.ajaxBtn = document.querySelectorAll('*[ajax-btn]')
this.ajaxBtns = [].slice.call(this.ajaxBtn)

this.ajaxBtns.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let url = item.dataset.link
    console.log(url)
  })
})

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = this.responseText
    } else
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
        '<div class="loader">' +
        '<img src="/eigg/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width: 50px;height: auto;background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>'
  }

  xhttp.open('POST', 'content-store/detail/1720/savings-by-design', true)
  xhttp.send()
}

MicroModal.init({
  onShow: (modal) => loadDoc(),
  // [1]
  openTrigger: modalData, // [3]
  closeTrigger: modalClose, // [4]
  openClass: 'is-open', // [5]
  disableScroll: true, // [6]
  disableFocus: false, // [7]
  awaitOpenAnimation: true, // [8]
  awaitCloseAnimation: true, // [9]
  debugMode: false, // [10]
})
```

so I am trying to get let url = item.dataset.link into the loadDoc() function where the hard coded link appears at the moment xhttp.open('POST', 'content-store/detail/1720/savings-by-design', true)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the problem correctly but couldn't you just give your `loadDoc()` an argument `url` and in your event listener just call `loadDoc(url)` instead of logging it to the console? On a unrelated note: have a look at the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for making requests.

Comment: Please give us HTML code also

Comment: What happens when you try to console.log(url)?  Do you get some error?  I would try changing `let url = item.dataset.link` to `let url = this.dataset.link`, I think the problem is that it doesn't know what `item` is when the click actually happens.  It would be easier to tell with an error message.

Comment: Thanks Mushroomator that works I will checkout the Fetch API as well. Many thanks